# Cannot determine the artifact identity of the file

Tags: osgi, eclipse-virgo, spring-dm

I was getting import package exception, which i solved using menifist file. But now i am getting other excepotions which i have no idea, i am able to deploy simple bundle, but this particular bundle is not running on virgo server from pickup directory.

I have attached the server log and the error i come across.

looking forward to hear from you.

```
    [2012-08-30 22:43:43.250] fs-watcher                   <DE0014I> Uninstalled bundle 'tasknodebundle' version '0.0.0'.
[2012-08-30 22:44:56.453] fs-watcher                   <HD0001I> Hot deployer processing 'CREATED' event for file 'tasknodebundle.jar'.
[2012-08-30 22:44:56.468] fs-watcher                   <DE0701E> Cannot determine the artifact identity of the file 'C:\VIRGO-~1.REL\pickup\tasknodebundle.jar'.
[2012-08-30 22:44:56.484] fs-watcher                   <HD0002E> Hot deploy failed for file 'tasknodebundle.jar'. org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.DeploymentException: Cannot determine the artifact identity of the file 'C:\VIRGO-~1.REL\pickup\tasknodebundle.jar': uri='file:/C:/VIRGO-~1.REL/pickup/tasknodebundle.jar': uri='file:/C:/VIRGO-~1.REL/pickup/tasknodebundle.jar'
        at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.doInstall(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.install(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:139)
        at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.deploy(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:252)
        at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.hot.HotDeploymentFileSystemListener.deploy(HotDeployerFileSystemListener.java:163)
        at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.hot.HotDeploymentFileSystemListener.onChange(HotDeployerFileSystemListener.java:67)
        at org.eclipse.virgo.util.io.FileSystemChecker.notifyListeners(FileSystemChecker.java:245)
        at org.eclipse.virgo.util.io.FileSystemChecker.check(FileSystemChecker.java:166)
        at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.hot.WatchTask.run(WatchTask.java:48)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.DeploymentException: Cannot determine the artifact identity of the file 'C:\VIRGO-~1.REL\pickup\tasknodebundle.jar': uri='file:/C:/VIRGO-~1.REL/pickup/tasknodebundle.jar'
        at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.determineIdentity(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:209)
        at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.doInstall(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:159)
        ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.DeploymentException: Cannot determine the artifact identity of the file 'C:\VIRGO-~1.REL\pickup\tasknodebundle.jar'
        at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.determineIdentity(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:348)
        at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.determineIdentity(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:207)
        ... 9 common frames omitted
```

menifest file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: task-node-bundle
Bundle-SymbolicName: task-node-bundle
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Export-Package: com.ccl.aws.swf.nodes
Bundle-Vendor: Test user
Import-Package: com.ccl.aws.swf.nodes; version="0.0.0",
 com.ccl.aws.swf.nodes.util; version="0.0.0",
 com.amazonaws.services.ec2; version="1.3.14",
 com.amazonaws.services.s3; version="1.3.14",
 com.amazonaws.services.sns; version="1.3.14",
 com.amazonaws.services.sqs; version="1.3.14",
 com.amazonaws.auth; version="1.3.14"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the manifest file? I guess the problem is there. The file format of the manifest files can be tricky, really small things like a space, backslash or a line that's too long will mess it up.

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: task-node-bundle
Bundle-SymbolicName: task-node-bundle
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Export-Package: com.ccl.aws.swf.nodes
Bundle-Vendor: Waqas Sadiq
Import-Package: com.ccl.aws.swf.nodes; version="0.0.0",
 com.ccl.aws.swf.nodes.util; version="0.0.0",
 com.amazonaws.services.ec2; version="1.3.14",
 com.amazonaws.services.s3; version="1.3.14",
 com.amazonaws.services.sns; version="1.3.14",
 com.amazonaws.services.sqs; version="1.3.14",
 com.amazonaws.auth; version="1.3.14"